# I want to find \$\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\hat{T}}\$

Tags: control-system, control-theory

I have the following block diagram, and I want to find the transfer function \$\frac{\hat{\theta}}{\hat{T}}\$. I am not sure how to do this, I've got the rules of connection in a series or parallel, but I am stuck.

[image: Block Diagram]
I started with the entrance of \$T\$ but got stuck, can someone please provide me some help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This kind of block diagram doesn't have anything to do with the rules for parallel and series connections of impedances. It just represents a bunch of complex algebraic equations. Each of the rectangular boxes just produces an output variable by multiplying its input by a constant, given by the text in the box.

For example,

\$ V_m = \gamma(I_{ref}-I_m)\$ comes from the first box at the upper left.

\$ I_m = \dfrac{1}{Ls+R}(V_m - E_{emf})\$ comes from the next box to the right.

You can keep making equations like this for each variable in the diagram. 
At that point you should have a complete set of equations that you can reduce to get a relationship between \$\Omega\$ and *T*.

To do this for a complex system like yours, you may want to polish up your skills in a symbolic math package like Maple or Mathematica.